# Adsense linking gives error 403 forbidden nginx/1.16.0

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, adsense

I am using wordpress theme (color mag) in my blog http://www.darshaktech.com

I am trying to add Google AdSense to my wordpress site. I have used [Site Kit plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-site-kit/) for that. But when I click on `Wordpress dashboard -> SiteKit-> Start setup->Selecting google account->Signed in` it gives me the erro :

> 403 forbidden ngnix/1.16.0

I have tried the following things:

- There is only one Google account associated from my name.
- Deleting .htaccess file
- Changing permalink
- Giving read write permission in FTP portal.
- Reinstalling SiteKit plugin as well as all plugin associate with my blog.
- Reinstalling colormag theme.
- Clear cookies & history of browser.

How can we solve this? I just want to add Google Adsense into my website.

Comment: I also faced a similar issue, I wasn't able to solve, I skipped Site Kit plugin & installed in manually.

Comment: @Earid how can I add header code in colormag theme

Comment: theme edit > footer.php , or use header footer script plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue so I contacted my hosting providers who advised that I should turn off Mod Security in CPanel which worked perfect for me.